# Underbraces in formula pointing to text part 2

Tags: equations, amsmath, braces

This post is building from the post found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267854/underbraces-in-formula-pointing-to-text) developed by Gonzalo Medina.  How to get the same equation to behave correctly on two different pages?  In my code, the under braces do not fall in the correct position.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  L_{\omega_{m}}=\frac{1}{8}\dfrac{FkT}{\tikzmark{starta}P_{s~av}\tikzmark{enda}}\dfrac{\omega_{o}^{2}}{\omega_{m}^{2}}\left(\dfrac{P_{in}}{\tikzmark{startb}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endb}}%
  + \dfrac{1}{\tikzmark{startc}Q_{unl}\tikzmark{endc}}+\dfrac{P_{sig}}{\tikzmark{startd}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endd}} \right)^{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\omega_{c}}{\tikzmark{starte}\omega_{m}\tikzmark{ende}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Value/\Length/\Text in {%
  a/15pt/{Phase\\perturbation},%
  b/40pt/{Input power\\over\\reactive power},%
  c/20pt/{Resonator $Q$},%
  d/40pt/{Signal power\\over\\reactive power},%
  e/20pt/{Flicker\\effect}%
  }
{
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  ({pic cs:start\Value}) -- coordinate (aux-\Value) ({pic cs:end\Value}|-{pic cs:start\Value});
\draw
  ([yshift=-7pt]aux-\Value) -- ++(0pt,-\Length)
  node[below,align=center] {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-4]


\begin{equation}
  L_{\omega_{m}}=\frac{1}{8}\dfrac{FkT}{\tikzmark{starta}P_{s~av}\tikzmark{enda}}\dfrac{\omega_{o}^{2}}{\omega_{m}^{2}}\left(\dfrac{P_{in}}{\tikzmark{startb}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endb}}%
  + \dfrac{1}{\tikzmark{startc}Q_{unl}\tikzmark{endc}}+\dfrac{P_{sig}}{\tikzmark{startd}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endd}} \right)^{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\omega_{c}}{\tikzmark{starte}\omega_{m}\tikzmark{ende}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Value/\Length/\Text in {%
  a/15pt/{Phase\\perturbation},%
  b/40pt/{Input power\\over\\reactive power},%
  c/20pt/{Resonator $Q$},%
  d/40pt/{Signal power\\over\\reactive power},%
  e/20pt/{Flicker\\effect}%
  }
{
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  ({pic cs:start\Value}) -- coordinate (aux-\Value) ({pic cs:end\Value}|-{pic cs:start\Value});
\draw
  ([yshift=-7pt]aux-\Value) -- ++(0pt,-\Length)
  node[below,align=center] {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: @erik, I did compile more than twice.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from your question where the correct position should be, but I assume you want text pointing to underbraces in the first equation as well. This is not happening in your example because you identify everything using the same names both times. As a result, `start\value` and `end\value` are overwritten in equation two, and you only get text pointing to those underbraces. Changing the labels will fix this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  L_{\omega_{m}}=\frac{1}{8}\dfrac{FkT}{\tikzmark{starta}P_{s~av}\tikzmark{enda}}\dfrac{\omega_{o}^{2}}{\omega_{m}^{2}}\left(\dfrac{P_{in}}{\tikzmark{startb}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endb}}%
  + \dfrac{1}{\tikzmark{startc}Q_{unl}\tikzmark{endc}}+\dfrac{P_{sig}}{\tikzmark{startd}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endd}} \right)^{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\omega_{c}}{\tikzmark{starte}\omega_{m}\tikzmark{ende}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Value/\Length/\Text in {%
  a/15pt/{Phase\\perturbation},%
  b/40pt/{Input power\\over\\reactive power},%
  c/20pt/{Resonator $Q$},%
  d/40pt/{Signal power\\over\\reactive power},%
  e/20pt/{Flicker\\effect}%
  }
{
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  ({pic cs:start\Value}) -- coordinate (aux-\Value) ({pic cs:end\Value}|-{pic cs:start\Value});
\draw
  ([yshift=-7pt]aux-\Value) -- ++(0pt,-\Length)
  node[below,align=center] {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{3cm}
\lipsum[1-3]


\begin{equation}
  L_{\omega_{m}}=\frac{1}{8}\dfrac{FkT}{\tikzmark{startf}P_{s~av}\tikzmark{endf}}\dfrac{\omega_{o}^{2}}{\omega_{m}^{2}}\left(\dfrac{P_{in}}{\tikzmark{startg}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endg}}%
  + \dfrac{1}{\tikzmark{starth}Q_{unl}\tikzmark{endh}}+\dfrac{P_{sig}}{\tikzmark{starti}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endi}} \right)^{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\omega_{c}}{\tikzmark{startj}\omega_{m}\tikzmark{endj}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Value/\Length/\Text in {%
  f/15pt/{Phase\\perturbation},%
  g/40pt/{Input power\\over\\reactive power},%
  h/20pt/{Resonator $Q$},%
  i/40pt/{Signal power\\over\\reactive power},%
  j/20pt/{Flicker\\effect}%
  }
{
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  ({pic cs:start\Value}) -- coordinate (aux-\Value) ({pic cs:end\Value}|-{pic cs:start\Value});
\draw
  ([yshift=-7pt]aux-\Value) -- ++(0pt,-\Length)
  node[below,align=center] {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU for your solution.  I did want the text pointing to underbraces in the first equation as well.  Your solution works perfectly!

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. My initial comment about compiling twice was a knee-jerk response, but when I took a look at the code I saw what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

> How to get the same equation to behave correctly on two different pages?

The `book` class defaults to `twoside` typsetting. So, in two different pages the margins are different and your labels need to be corrected accordingly. Using the xshift value of :

```
xshift=\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\oddsidemargin+\marginparsep
```

would compensate for this in an odd page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  L_{\omega_{m}}=\frac{1}{8}\dfrac{FkT}{\tikzmark{starta}P_{s~av}\tikzmark{enda}}\dfrac{\omega_{o}^{2}}{\omega_{m}^{2}}\left(\dfrac{P_{in}}{\tikzmark{startb}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endb}}%
  + \dfrac{1}{\tikzmark{startc}Q_{unl}\tikzmark{endc}}+\dfrac{P_{sig}}{\tikzmark{startd}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endd}} \right)^{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\omega_{c}}{\tikzmark{starte}\omega_{m}\tikzmark{ende}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,xshift=\dimexpr-\leftmargin-\oddsidemargin+\marginparsep]
\foreach \Value/\Length/\Text in {%
  a/15pt/{Phase\\perturbation},%
  b/40pt/{Input power\\over\\reactive power},%
  c/20pt/{Resonator $Q$},%
  d/40pt/{Signal power\\over\\reactive power},%
  e/20pt/{Flicker\\effect}%
  }
{
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  ({pic cs:start\Value}) -- coordinate (aux-\Value) ({pic cs:end\Value}|-{pic cs:start\Value});
\draw
  ([yshift=-7pt]aux-\Value) -- ++(0pt,-\Length)
  node[below,align=center] {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{3cm}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\begin{equation}
  L_{\omega_{m}}=\frac{1}{8}\dfrac{FkT}{\tikzmark{starta}P_{s~av}\tikzmark{enda}}\dfrac{\omega_{o}^{2}}{\omega_{m}^{2}}\left(\dfrac{P_{in}}{\tikzmark{startb}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endb}}%
  + \dfrac{1}{\tikzmark{startc}Q_{unl}\tikzmark{endc}}+\dfrac{P_{sig}}{\tikzmark{startd}\omega_{o}W_{e}\tikzmark{endd}} \right)^{2} \left(1 + \dfrac{\omega_{c}}{\tikzmark{starte}\omega_{m}\tikzmark{ende}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \Value/\Length/\Text in {%
  a/15pt/{Phase\\perturbation},%
  b/40pt/{Input power\\over\\reactive power},%
  c/20pt/{Resonator $Q$},%
  d/40pt/{Signal power\\over\\reactive power},%
  e/20pt/{Flicker\\effect}%
  }
{
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt}]
  ({pic cs:start\Value}) -- coordinate (aux-\Value) ({pic cs:end\Value}|-{pic cs:start\Value});
\draw
  ([yshift=-7pt]aux-\Value) -- ++(0pt,-\Length)
  node[below,align=center] {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here are two images from two successive pages:

[image]

[image]